# I need help understanding this recursive code

Tags: java, recursion

the question is "Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit."

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(persistence(39));
    //System.out.println(persistence(999));
}
public static int persistence(long n) {
    long m = 1, r = n;

    if (r / 10 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for(r = n; r!= 0; r /=10){
        m *= r % 10;
    }
    //System.out.println(m);
    return persistence(m) + 1;
}
```

I understand that the if statement is for when its finally a single digit and it'll return 0. If i could get an explanation on the m variable and what its there for. What the for loop does and when it returns persistence(m) why there is a + 1 on it.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation will comes likes this .

let us understand the problem statement.

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num
>   and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of
>   times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single
>   digit."

Say : 39

> which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num
>   until you reach a single digit.

So, we need to do like this to satisfy the above statement.

```
39 = 3*9 = 27  (1 time) - persistance(39)
27 = 2*7 = 14  (2rd time)  - persistance(27)
14 = 1*4 = 4   (3rd time)- persistance(14)
```

So, according to the problem statement we come to the single digit.

> you can take reference of the below, understand it .

[image]

> why there is a + 1 on it.

to count the number of times the recursive function done the calculation.